# weblogic - controlling the thread count of a web app

Tags: weblogic

I'd like to control how many threads can be used by a web application.
So far I thought it can be set by creating an application-scope workmanager `(Deployments -> [application] -> Configuration -> Workload)` and setting the Maximum Thread Constraint.
However recently I have the feeling that it is not true as this workmanager should be referenced from the code so it has to be used explicitly from the application.
What I'd need is to configure that from now on the XYZ application can use max 5 threads but no more. It can be done on global level but I want to control only one application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you define the workmanager in app's `weblogic.xml` or `weblogic-application.xml`, it's for sure will work on application level instead of `config.xml` which is domain-level config.
If you create and configurate the workmanager's `max-threads-constraint` and then reference to it in your app’s `web.xm`l file like this:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>wl-dispatch-policy</param-name>
   <param-value>your_workmanager_name</param-value>
</init-param>
```

i'm pretty sure, that this constraint will apply only on certain app's level.

> I have the feeling that it is not true as this workmanager should be referenced from the code so it has to be used explicitly from the application.

Where'd you find this? I may be wrong but I never heard or read that it should be referenced explicitly from code instead of xml.

For more details take a look [on this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1067159) and [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_server_performance_and_tuning1) in case you hadn't.